# How do I combine two statement will be one query?

Tags: php, mysql

Here an example queries to get two type of icons..

```
$fetchIcon = array();
$queryIcon = $db->query("SELECT * FROM icon_code WHERE icon_type = 'icon'");
while ($fIcon = $db->fetch_assoc($queryIcon)) {
    $fetchIcon[] = $fIcon;
}

$fetchOther = array();
$queryOther = $db->query("SELECT * FROM icon_code WHERE icon_type = 'other'");
while ($fOther = $db->fetch_assoc($queryOther)) {
    $fetchOther[] = $fOther;
}
```

Then I use `foreach` to show an ouput on the same page.

```
foreach ($fetchIcon as $Icon) {
  echo $Icon['IconName']; // select option for Icon
}

foreach ($fetchOther as $Other) {
  echo $Other['IconName']; // select option for other icon
}
```

**Question :**
How do I combine the two statement will be one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM icon_code
WHERE icon_type IN ('icon', 'other')
```

and then

```
$fetchIcon = array();
$fetchOther = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    switch($row['icon_type']) {
       case 'icon':
           $fetchIcon[] = $row;
           break;
       case 'other':
       default:
           $fetchOther[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM icon_code 
WHERE icon_type = 'icon' 
or icon_type = 'other' 
ORDER BY icon_type
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM icon_code 
WHERE icon_type in ('icon', 'other')
ORDER BY icon_type
```

The `order by`is optional to get the order by type.

Comment: Add `ORDER BY icon_type` to get the exact same output.

Comment: Or, more generally, a `UNION ALL` will do.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function:

```
$queryOther = $db->query("SELECT * FROM icon_code WHERE icon_type IN ('other', 'icon'");
```